# Firebase cloud functions with openai error deploying fuctions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, openapi

when I tried deploy it give me this error :
Could not create or update Cloud Run service firstcall, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'firstcall-00001-jel' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=clouddeneme-6f208&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/firstcall/revision_name/firstcall-00001-jel&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22firstcall%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22firstcall-00001-jel%22
For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        firstCall(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
!  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/clouddeneme-6f208/us-central1/gcf-artifacts
Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I tried this code its not deploying:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {Configuration, OpenAIApi} = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
initializeApp();
exports.firstCall = onRequest({maxInstances: 10}, async (request, response) => {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
  });
  response.send(chatCompletion);
});
```

Comment: We can't see your logs URL.  Even if we could, it's required on Stack Overflow to copy all relevant data into the question so that it's available in the future to anyone who comes across this question later.  Please try to figure out the important parts of the log and edit the question to show them.

Comment: if i click on the link the log is the same as above how can I find out ?

Comment: having the same issue too, how did you solve it?

Comment: Did you please manage to solve this.. help wanted !!